# Is it possible to use XCode with a local macOS account?

Tags: icloud, xcode, apple-id

I've been given a MacBook by my workplace and it's set up with a local account with no linked apple ID to the user account.

I want to try out iOS development on the machine, but in order to deploy an app to my iPhone, XCode requires an Apple ID. My question is in two parts:

1. Is it possible to deploy an application to my iPhone without using an AppleID? - I don't want to associate my personal apple ID in any way with my work laptop, and since my company set me up with a local account I don't have a company apple ID either.
2. If I give an Apple ID to XCode, will it link that Apple ID to any other part of the macbook (eg. assign it to my local account in Users & Groups, log in toiMessage, iCloud, App Store etc) or is it completely contained inside XCode/the XCode project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not in any easy manner
2. No - you have to enter your Apple ID in each place and setting and application unless you consent to easy setup when making a new account or when the OS is new.

My general recommendation, is make a work AppleID if you are paid to develop and never use your personal iCloud on any work development or device, ever. I’m not so strict on Apple App Store - putting personal apps on a work computer isn’t likely to cause big issues unless you set automatic downloads, but why risk any of that?

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you. Making a work-only apple ID would be easy enough, I was just worried it might insert itself onto Users & Groups and potentially make a problem with my workplace. I'm pretty sure they don't have DEP (hence the local account) but still, would rather err on the side of caution.

Comment: For sure, some workplaces try to manage work related Apple ID but you should be fine no matter what they choose - it’s totally cool to use a personal SMS for second factor as well. Apple doesn’t link accounts based on SMS confirmation of account sign in so you can use the same sms for multiple AppleID